# PrimaryPreferred preference for replica set not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Assume I got two servers for the same mongodb replica set - one with mongodb primary and the other with a secondary and a arbiter. Im using Node.JS to access the db (https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native). after i manually disconnect the connection between those servers, the primary becomes secondary and the secondary a primary because of the arbiter. now, i want to be allowed to read from the secondary. my code looks like:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , format = require('util').format;

var url = format("mongodb://%s,%s,%s/%s?replicaSet=%s&readPreference=%s"
  , "localhost:27017",
  , "localhost:27018"
  , "localhost:27019"
  , "exampleDb"
  , "foo"
  , "primaryPreferred");

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");

    var collection = db.collection('somecollection');
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, items) {
      // Done reading from secondary if available
    })
  }
});
```

but it says that no replica set member available for query with ReadPreference undefined and tags undefined. what should I do ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this error? Unless your deployment is identical to the [example code](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_1and2_2.html#read-preferences) you copied, it sounds like you may have your parameters mismatched (since ReadPreference is undefined). If you are still having trouble I would post your exact code (with the host names redacted).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set slaveOk: "true". This will enable queries on secondary and then you will able to query.

Regards,
Sheraz Javed

Comment: Read preferences *replace* the older `slaveOk` setting, and if set will take precedence (ref: [MongoClient or how to connect in a new and better way](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html)).